# How to find out the IP range for a certain country code in python?

Tags: python, geolocation, maxmind, ip2location

Is there a way to figure out the IP ranges for a certain country code without using [MaxMind](https://pypi.org/project/maxminddb/) or [IP2Location](https://www.ip2location.com/development-libraries/ip2location/python) where in both they provide a binary file where one have to check single IP at a time

both source do not provide a way to list the ranges for a certain country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do provide data files in CSV / text format. See example below.

https://www.ip2location.com/samples/db1-ip-country.txt

Comment: In this approach one would have to check a single IP against the that file at a time you can retrieve the whole range without parsing that file into some dictionary that has a country and the IP ranges for that single country